# What is going wrong in this simulation using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, graphics

I am trying to simulate the non-linear KdV using NDSolve with initial condition -2Sech^2(x) and periodic boundary conditions. Here is my code:

```
a = 30;

eq = {D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 3}] == 
6 u[t, x] D[u[t, x], {x, 1}], u[0, x] == -2 Sech[x] ^2, 
u[t, -a] == u[t, a]};

sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a}, MaxStepSize -> 0.14];

data = Flatten[Table[{t, x, u[t, x]} /. sol, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a}], 
2];

ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-30, 30}, {-2, 2}}, Lighting -> "Automatic", 
AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

The output is correct at first but then something unexpected happens:

[image]

What is going wrong here? Normally the peaked-shaped object would continue to propagate.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's just a glitch with too big a `MaxStepSize`:

`sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a}, MaxStepSize -> .07];`

yields:

[image]

Comment: I compared this method with some alternatives in my answer, in case you're interested. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to pick a better method for approximating the derivatives.  Setting `"DifferenceOrder"` to either `6` or `"Pseudospectral"` solves the problem.

```
sol6 = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
      "TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> 6},
    "TemporalVariable" -> t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.66469, Null}  *)

solSP = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
      "TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"},
    "TemporalVariable" -> t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.22224, Null}  *)
```

Note that the spatial discretization corresponding to `"MaxStepSize" -> 0.07` is equivalent to `"MinPoints" -> 858`.  However, the option `MaxStepSize -> 0.07` used by itself also limits the time steps.

```
sol07s = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
      "TensorProductGrid", "MaxStepSize" -> 0.07},
    "TemporalVariable" -> t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.95492, Null}  *)

sol858 = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
      "TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 858},
    "TemporalVariable" -> t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.10221, Null}  *)

sol07 = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -a, a},  (* John Joseph M. Carrasco *)
  MaxStepSize -> .07]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {6.75514, Null}  *)
```

The two with only a limitation on spatial discretization are the same:

```
sol858 === sol07s
(*  True  *)
```

But the last way `sol07`, which limits both the spatial and time step size, is different:

```
Length /@ First[u["Coordinates"] /. sol858]
Length /@ First[u["Coordinates"] /. sol07]
(*
  {173, 859}
  {432, 859}
*)
```

By comparison, the `"DifferenceOrder"` adjustment yields a smaller solution (with respect to the number of steps and memory):

```
Length /@ First[u["Coordinates"] /. sol6]
Length /@ First[u["Coordinates"] /. solSP]
(*
  {173, 491}
  {175, 239}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice!  Very clear analysis, and educational!